# how to identify kernel problems from message log file

Tags: linux, redhat, kernel, dmesg

dear friends and colleges

we notice about unexpected freezed of one of our critical linux machines server linux - version - 7.2

this is VM machines

and now I am working to understand what the root cause that server was freezed

from the messages log I see lines that never seen on other machine ( or maybe I am wrong )

```
Feb  7 10:32:34 little_indian_boy kernel: Linux version 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-034.build.eng.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Thu Oct 29 17:29:29 EDT 2015
Feb  7 10:32:34 little_indian_boy kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/vg00-lv_root ro crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=vg00/lv_root rd.lvm.lv=vg00/lv_swap rhgb quiet LANG=en_US.UTF-8
Feb  7 10:32:34 little_indian_boy kernel: Disabled fast string operations
Feb  7 10:32:34 little_indian_boy kernel: e820: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
Feb  7 10:32:34 little_indian_boy kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009efff] usable
Feb  7 10:32:34 little_indian_boy kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009f000-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
Feb  7 10:32:34 little_indian_boy kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000dc000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
Feb  7 10:32:34 little_indian_boy kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x00000000bfedffff] usable
Feb  7 10:32:34 little_indian_boy kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000bfee0000-0x00000000bfefefff] ACPI data
Feb  7 10:32:34 little_indian_boy kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000bfeff000-0x00000000bfefffff] ACPI NVS
Feb  7 10:32:34 little_indian_boy kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000bff00000-0x00000000bfffffff] usable
Feb  7 10:32:34 little_indian_boy kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000f0000000-0x00000000f7ffffff] reserved
Feb  7 10:32:34 little_indian_boy kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fec00000-0x00000000fec0ffff] reserved
Feb  7 10:32:34 little_indian_boy kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fee00000-0x00000000fee00fff] reserved
Feb  7 10:32:34 little_indian_boy kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fffe0000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
Feb  7 10:32:34 little_indian_boy kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000203fffffff] usable
Feb  7 10:32:34 little_indian_boy kernel: NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
Feb  7 10:32:34 little_indian_boy kernel: SMBIOS 2.7 present.
Feb  7 10:32:34 little_indian_boy kernel: Hypervisor detected: VMware
Feb  7 10:32:34 little_indian_boy kernel: AGP: No AGP bridge found
Feb  7 10:32:34 little_indian_boy kernel: e820: last_pfn = 0x2040000 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
Feb  7 10:32:34 little_indian_boy kernel: x86 PAT enabled: cpu 0, old 0x7040600070406, new 0x7010600070106
Feb  7 10:32:34 little_indian_boy kernel: total RAM covered: 261120M
Feb  7 10:32:34 little_indian_boy kernel: gran_size: 64K #011chunk_size: 64K #011num_reg: 8  #011lose cover RAM: 0G
Feb  7 10:32:34 little_indian_boy kernel: gran_size: 64K #011chunk_size: 128K #011num_reg: 8  #011lose cover RAM: 0G
Feb  7 10:32:34 little_indian_boy kernel: gran_size: 64K #011chunk_size: 256K #011num_reg: 8  #011lose cover RAM: 0G
Feb  7 10:32:34 little_indian_boy kernel: gran_size: 64K #011chunk_size: 512K #011num_reg: 8  #011lose cover RAM: 0G
Feb  7 10:32:34 little_indian_boy kernel: gran_size: 64K #011chunk_size: 1M #011num_reg: 8  #011lose cover RAM: 0G
Feb  7 10:32:34 little_indian_boy kernel: gran_size: 64K #011chunk_size: 2M #011num_reg: 8  #011lose cover RAM: 0G
Feb  7 10:32:34 little_indian_boy kernel: gran_size: 64K #011chunk_size: 4M #011num_reg: 8  #011lose cover RAM: 0G
Feb  7 10:32:34 little_indian_boy kernel: gran_size: 64K #011chunk_size: 8M #011num_reg: 8  #011lose cover RAM: 0G
Feb  7 10:32:34 little_indian_boy kernel: gran_size: 64K #011chunk_size: 16M #011num_reg: 8  #011lose cover RAM: 0G
is this lines are indicate on problem ?

gran_size: 64K #011chunk_size: 16M #011num_reg: 8 #011lose cover RAM: 0G
```

we also see that

```
 kernel: mtrr_cleanup: can not find optimal value
 kernel: please specify mtrr_gran_size/mtrr_chunk_size
 e820: last_pfn = 0xc0000 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
 found SMP MP-table at [mem 0x000f6a80-0x000f6a8f] mapped at [ffff8800000f6a80]
 kernel: Using GB pages for direct mapping
```

Comment: Set the VM hardware version to the highest available in your VMware setup, and install all available updates on this system.

Comment: @ Michael Hampton , what you mean about - Set the VM hardware version to the highest available in your VMware setup , do you mean some update on the VM HW ? or maybe some update on the OS , or else ?

Comment: Your Linux "server" is a VMware virtual machine.

Comment: ok , in this case do you mean to install the most update vmware tool ? https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1447193

Comment: No, I mean change the hardware version in the VMware virtual machine configuration.

Comment: in this case can you please give more details

Comment: That IS all the details!

Comment: ok but actually I not understand if you mean to upgrade v sphere client or maybe some firmware HW ?

Comment: No, you _use_ the vSphere client to make the change!

Comment: so I am understanding that we need to upgrade the -  firmware HW  ?

Comment: Have you no experience with vSphere? This is a very common operation.

Comment: actually no , I am sorry for that